# problem creating a fact of the day agent with dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to make my first chatbot for the Google assistant using dialogflow. I have no development skills.
What I try is to make a chatbot that gives the user a "fact of the day" wen the user say a date.

What I have done:

- Update the "Default Welcome Intent":
  The chatbot asks the user to give a date. An example: 6 october 2010.
- I created a new intent called 06/10/2010
  As training phrases I put in: 6 october 2010, 6 oktober, oktober 2010, oktober, 2010
  As entity I selected: @sys:date-time (not required).
  As response a fact about 6 december 2010.

What are the problems I have:

- It works fine when a user says one of the trained phrases but when he says something like: "december" or "1986" the test app closes and my google home asks me: "who do you want to call?"
- When I set the entity as required and the user says "december" or "1986" the Agent replies with the fact of 6 October 2010.

What I want:

- When a user says "October" the Agent replies with a random fact of October no matter what day or year.
- When a user says "2010" the Agent replies with a fact that happend in "2010".

In that context I have an extra question:

- If I put lets say "October" as training phrase in more than one intent will the Google Assistant randomly choose one response?

Does someone can help me and explain what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: This is a very similar to drop down to *Default [Fallback](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-default#fallback) Intent*, once the agent could not recognize any matching pattern throughout the training phrases looking into the example with not required entity. Have you tried to make a separate intent a part of default welcome one to check the behavior?